# Troubleshooting desktop PC not booting if network and USB ports are connected

Tags: usb, boot, networking, power-supply, reboot

My current desktop machine is composed by:

Intel q6600
Gigabyte EP43-DSL3
4GB DDR3
2HD S-ATA 750MB Seagate
DVD-RW S-ATA

Keyboard, webcam, headphones and the usual stuff connected to the USB ports.

Now, whenever I shut down my computer, I need to disconnect all USB ports and the network cable in order to make my computer boot up. Failing to do so, the computer simply refuses to turn on.

Other than that, the machine is rock solid once on.

Anybody knows what could be the cause if this weird behavior? Maybe the power supply?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here but could it be that the boot order of your computer has Network and USB above hard disk in the order of operating system boot preference.

When you say it refuses to turn on does it actually not turn on at all or it locks whilst trying to turn on?

You can view/change the boot order by accessing the bios when you computer initially starts up usually by pressing F12 or F2

Comment: no, this is not the problem. The computer is just not turning on. I checked the bios too, I'm positive I didn't select network as a boot option.